# How to properly pass json to a view

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view with some javascript code for a pie chart in it. This view has an action method, where I am running some queries an converting the results to json in order to fill the pie chart with something.

The problem is that I don't know (and couldn't understand from another questions here) how to properly return a json from action to view and actually work with the data in some way in the view.

Currently, what I have give me a json string in my browser instead of a view.

I do not have a model in my project for the data that's in in the json.

Here's all the code from my view :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">




      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
          ['German',  5.85],
          ['French',  1.66],
          ['Italian', 0.316],
          ['Romansh', 0.0791]
        ]);

      var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        pieSliceText: 'label',
        title: 'Accumulated experience',
        pieStartAngle: 100,
      };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>



<div id="piechart" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

And here is my controller :

```
 public ActionResult experiencePieChart()
        {
            //some queries
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(perclist);
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answer has nothing about a view in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller method should return `JsonResult`, just change it's signature in following way:

```
public JsonResult experiencePieChart()
{
    var perclist = ...
    //some queries
    return Json(perclist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

then in your `js` code you could call it

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get("/YourController/experiencePieChart",ShowPieChart,"json").fail(ShowPieChartFail);
});
```

of course then you need define `ShowPieChart` function which will render that graph

```
function ShowPieChart(chartData){
    // this code will be executed after result is returned asynchronously
    // chartData contains JSON representation of perclist variable
}
```

In case you'd like to do that data-transfer just on each refresh of page, you could store data required for chart. In your `.cshtml` you'd just add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ChartData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.MyData))
</script>
```

then during execution of `js` on `client` side you'd have `ChartData` variable initialized. Anyway this way have multiple downside and is not scalable at all. Going with `ajax` call seems much better to me.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your are returning **ActionResult** or **JsonResult** both are same, in fact if you check this inheritance hierarchy [ActionResult Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx)  you will find **JsonResult** is just a subtype of **ActionResult**. The only thing is if you want to expose more information about controller interface and it's behavior use concrete class else use **ActionResult**  if an action should return different types of results.

Comment: I don't agree it would not matter. Why you would use 'more' in case 'less' is enough to cover use-case. There is no single reason to use ActionResult in prior of JsonResult unless there is some consumer view needing it as ActionResult. This helps keep your project more self explanatory since it says something about how it's considered to be consumed but from here it starts to be philosophy ... ;)